# "Manage display" tab missing in Manage fields window

Tags: 7, entities, nodes

I am editing and working with fields for a Content type but can only see Field settings, widget type and delete tabs. The Manage display tab is missing.

How do I make it display?

I am running drupal 7

Comment: Are you doing this purely through the gui interface, or are you generating the content types in code?

Answer (score 1):

The tab might just be somewhere else. When you edit a content type, you see at least two tabs (provided that the core "Field UI" module is enabled):

- Manage Fields
- Manage Display

If you go to "Manage Fields" and then click on "Edit" for a given field, you will see the "Field Settings", "Widget type" and "Delete" tabs, as you say, but not the "Manage Display" tab. To see it, you need to go to the content type edit screen, it will display the list of fields and their display properties.

Hope that helps,

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [Form Builder](http://drupal.org/project/form_builder) module.

It's show the manage field,Display options on particular content type.

> This project allows users to build entire Form API structures through a graphical, AJAX-like interface. It has the ability to read and export FAPI arrays, and users are permitted to change any properties exposed by modules that expose forms to the Form Builder.